# Leading zeros on digital display: show or hide?

Tags: display

In everyday use of numbers, we normally show or write a leading zero only when it's the lone digit left of the decimal point. (Setting aside clocks.)

However, I've noticed that on some digital displays, leading zeroes are displayed. Examples:

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

What might be the rationale for this?  Is there some safety consideration? Such as reassuring the operator that they are seeing all the digits -- all digits are operating, and no digits are obscured from view by some intervening obstacle perhaps? Is there some related safety standard?

Comment: Are you asking more about there being _two_ zeroes (-00.39728) versus one (-0.39728) or versus none (-.39728)? If the latter case, I would say it's for clarity, because omitting the single zero is harder to quickly read (at least for me). In the former case, I expect it's just what Siglent is doing. My Keithley DMM6500 doesn't do that; it shows only one zero before the decimal point.

Comment: @JYelton  As I mentioned, the use of a leading zero in the first position to the left of the decimal point is quite standard in everyday writing of numbers, and on many displays, and not at issue here. As you say, that aids readability, where the DP can be hard to see otherwise.  My question is about showing additional leading zeroes in the second and above positions left of the DP.

Comment: @JYelton I added some other examples of displays with leading zeroes.  The ones using a graphical display are particularly curious, since there are no physically fixed digits, so the software has to go out of its way to set "excess" leading positions to zero (as opposed to blank).

Comment: I can only guess, but it's probably either to let you know what range the meter is in, or to let you know that the measurement could go that high.  All of those instruments that you're showing are high-end meters, or knockoffs thereof -- probably someone with a Marketing hat wanted to make sure that the bean-counters could see a lot of digits if they went to audit the lab where all the R&D money was going.

Comment: If the question is closed here it could be relevant on https://ux.stackexchange.com

Comment: Another possibility is that, in order to blank 2 or more leading zeros additional logic would be required which costs more money and is essentially unnecessary as everybody who is likely to use the equipment will be able to correctly interpret the numbers regardless.

Comment: @PeterJennings Well, ever since the ancient times of early TTL, 7-segment drivers have had provision for blanking leading zeros (eg: 7447 BI and RBO), though they might have required an additional gate to factor in the decimal point. So it was both a known conspicuous issue and had a solution.  And the barrier to solution is even far less where a graphical display is used. So I think commercial products showing the leading zeroes would have to be a positive choice.

Comment: i just found this interesting thread: Topic: Why do digital multimeters not have zero-blanking?  https://www.eevblog.com/forum/chat/why-do-digital-multimeters-not-have-zero-blanking/

Answer (score 4):

Possible reasons for displaying multiple leading zeros:-

1. The display hardware doesn't have the capability, and adding it would involve expensive additional circuitry.
2. It shows the dynamic range of the instrument (you immediately know the maximum number of digits that can be displayed).
3. It proves that the digits are working, so eg. a value of 21.0 is not mistaken for 1.0 because the tens digits is dead.
4. The display has special indicators such as '+' and '-' that are always at the far left, and would look 'disconnected' if there was a blank space between them and the number.
5. For consistency with other instruments that did it, eg. an older model or equivalent device.
6. Because it's aesthetically pleasing.

Examples:-

- Car odometer. Several of the points above apply:-

Traditional odometers use a mechanical system of rotating wheels with digits 0 to 9 marked on them. The mechanism required to blank leading zeros would be very complicated, for no great benefit.

You can tell by the number of digits how many miles/km it takes to 'clock' the counter (could be important if buying a used vehicle).

Car owners are familiar with this display format, so a modern electronic instrument panel might reproduce it even though digits could easily be blanked if desired.

Always showing all the digits keeps the display centered in its designated area, rather than being offset to the right by various amounts depending on the number of significant digits. The odometer is often centered on the instrument panel because it 'looks good' there.

- LCD multimeter with segmented display.

Special symbols are often placed at the far left, so showing all the digits keeps them close to the number.

- Devices using MSI or LSI chips that don't have leading zero blanking built in.

In 1978 I designed and built a multi purpose instrument with frequency counter, digital voltmeter and capacitance meter, based on the [MM74C925](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/mm74c926-1193654.pdf) 4-Digit Counter with Multiplexed
7-Segment Output Drivers. Because everything is done inside the chip, adding leading zero blanking was impracticable. Turns out this was good because recently it began intermittently dropping one segment from the left-most digit (due to a fault inside the LED module). I saw this fault as soon as it was turned on. With blanking I might not have realized that some numbers were being displayed incorrectly.

Expanding on this, the [ICL7106/7107](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/icl7106-icl7107-icl7107s-datasheet) 3-1/2 digit A/D converters were very popular ICs used in multimeters and panel meters, and can still be purchased today. They did not have leading zero blanking for one simple reason - where the decimal point is placed *depends on the application*. The chip has no way of knowing which digits would need to be blanked, and the 40 pin DIP package has no room for the extra input pins needed to tell it. As with the MM74C925, adding the functionality externally would be difficult.

Millions of multimeters have been produced using the ICL7106, setting an industry standard for multimeter displays. Some cheap multimeters sold today probably still use this IC (or a Chinese clone of it).

Comment: Yes, and I'd like to stress point 2. For instance the 34401A, a long-standing multimeter from HP/Agilent/Keysight, like similar models, has no visual indication of the selected range, which can be only inferred from the displayed leading zeros.

Comment: Bruce: I appreciate the effort, these are plausible explanations for leading zero displays.  But I'm not seeing strong positive rationales for deliberately doing it.  #2 is undermined by many instruments having ranges like 1999 or 5999 etc, where leftmost zero is misleading. #3 doesn't show you a bad segment G, which could display '8' as zero. An initial "display test" 8888 display would be better.  The other items are more or less aesthetic and debatable. Not denying these items might be behind some display format choices, just not finding them compelling reasons to favor or keep doing it.

Comment: @gwideman As you write, a "lamp test" or "display test" can be added to deal with Bruce's #3 and later paragraph about his 1978 design. And I think it's always a good idea to include as it tests every segment. But zero-inhibit does require added logic. From the leftmost side, an "inhibit if zero" is supplied as "true." If the digit compares to zero and has the "inhibit if zero" applied, then it inhibits the digit and passes along a "true" to the next digit to the right. But complications arrive with the decimal point position. So the logic isn't entirely trivial.

Comment: @gwideman _"a "lamp test" or "display test" can be added to deal with Bruce's... 1978 design"_ - not easily. I would have had to forgo the 74C925 for a 'discrete' design with multiple counter ICs etc., which would have been too large, complicated and expensive (the 74C925 was the inspiration for the project).

Comment: @BruceAbbott Yes, sorry, I didn't mean it was necessarily trivial back in 1978. I too faced such constraints back then. But we've long since moved on, and clearly many products with digital displays have suppressed excess left zeroes, even in the 70's (see 7447), to the point where not suppressing the left zeroes generally represents a deliberate design choice.

Comment: @periblepsis  As Bruce noted, zero blanking is not easy with 74C925. But zero blanking is easy when using 7447 or similar with /RBO and /RBI. Zero to the left of DP can be unblanked by just combining DP with the /RBO. Ie: Both the /RBO signal has to be low and and the DP drive has to be high (DP LED off) to command /RBI low (digit off if zero).  This is just one or two gates per digit, depending on the source of DP. But this debate about the 1970's is a bit off topic -- my question is really about what rationales there are when not suppressing the left-zeroes is a deliberate design choice.

Comment: I subsequently found this related EEVBlog forum discussion: "Why do digital multimeters not have zero-blanking?" https://www.eevblog.com/forum/chat/why-do-digital-multimeters-not-have-zero-blanking/ covering similar territory. From image searches I get the feeling HP/Agilent/Keysight are the most-prominent leading-zero non-blankers, but no rationale was obtained from a request to them, leaving speculation similar to here.

Comment: @gwideman yes, I read that thread when researching my answer. The original reasons may be lost in the past, but we can still make a good guess. Early instruments were expensive and the circuits were relatively crude, eg. my 1978 project. Before that mechanical counters with all digits shown were the norm. This was copied in electronic instruments, both because it was easier and what was expected. ISTR that back then leading zero blanking was an 'advanced' feature.

Comment: @gwideman What causes choice varies and I don't have the inside track speculating about how people think, from time to time. So I'll leave this to others.